# Lifecycle hook in Arduino to know if Arduino is reset or powered down

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I am new to Arduino programming and I'm really fascinated with its working. Is there a way to know if an Arduino is getting switched off or being reset? Like a function would be called before the Arduino gets switched off.

I want to detect this event *to preserve a value*, where a user resets his Arduino, or switches it off. Is it possible?

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to turn the problem around, if possible - Instead of doing something when the arduino is switched off, do it when it is switched on again.

Comment: If i want to preserve a value, then i have to know when its switched off

Comment: In this case, it's simply not possible without some external circuitry that (1) realises the switchoff and (2) keeps the arduino alive for some last gasp actions. Try to save your value in EEPROM if it doesn't update too often. Maybe you can give some more detail what you actually want to do.

Comment: EEPROM has a limit of 100,000 write/erase cycles, so we cant do more than that

Comment: Shutting off an Arduino is as simple as cutting off the power supply. As the voltage declines the Browout Detection could notice it but there won't be enough time to write any value into the EEPROM or write something out via serial. There simply is no such thing in the Arduino lifecycle. But you can use a pin and a button to externally trigger a write to EEPROM and then cut off the power.

Comment: @bukkehariprasad That's why I wrote "if it doesn't update too often" - Then accept it's not possible.

Comment: What value do you want to preserve? How often does it change? How big is it?

Answer (score 1):

> EEPROM has a limit of 100,000 write/erase cycles, so we cant do more than that

You have 1k bytes of EEPROM and they survive a minimum of 100,000 writes. So that's 102,400,000 writes you could potentially do, if you are saving one byte. Even at one write a second that would be around 3 years.

However the EEPROM page size is 4 bytes, so that is actually 25,600,000 writes you could get away with (of 4 bytes at a time). Still, that is quite a lot of writes.

A while back I tested one of my chip's EEPROM and found that it greatly exceeded the 100,000 writes specified before it starting misreading the data back.

Also, if you refrain from writing if the value hasn't changed (hopefully that's a lot of the time?) then you could probably extend the life to 100 years.

---

> Like a function would be called before the Arduino gets switched off.

No, that's impossible. How would it possibly know it is about to be switched off? Once it is switched off, functions are hardly going to be able to run.

---

> Is there a way to know if an Arduino is getting switched off or being reset?

Once you hit Reset the processor starts again. It doesn't run any functions "just before" or "just after" being reset (using the original variables). That would mean that the reset doesn't actually reset it.

---

If you are designing some gadget that lets you configure it (eg. with a volume control) then simply save the new setting to EEPROM when it is changed. This is hardly going to happen 24 hours a day.

Comment: Reset does not actually clear memory variables; instead default startup code added by the compiler does.  So in fact, code can run "just after reset" and before this happens in the case of a warm reset.

Comment: I understand that, however programming in C++ you would have difficulty in retrieving those variables. In any case, I don't see how you would recover variables after the power had been removed.

Comment: For a self-confessed novice to retrieve variables after a reset (and be able to tell the difference between valid variables and random data after being powered up) would not be easy.

Comment: Many things are difficult, but used.  Passing RAM variable in fixed locations across reboot is one of them.  Writing to persistent memory on loss of input power, before the capacitor your are running off of has drained is another.  Together, they can solve the problem.  But no, it won't be easy.

Comment: *Writing to persistent memory on loss of input power, before the capacitor your are running off of has drained is another. Together, they can solve the problem.* - well, Chris, the "Answer" button is there for you to explain how to achieve this. I'm sure the OP will appreciate your advice.

Comment: @NickGammon thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I am using file system now instead of eeprom to save data. I think its lifetime is more than the default storage provided by arduino.

Comment: @bukkehariprasad - actually the eeprom has a longer cycle life that whatever is hosting your file system.  Though a well designed flash translation layer could walk the data through more cells, limiting the wear on each one.  So each individual cell on an SDcard has shorter life, but you can write a given small chunk of data more times to a well engineered sd card system than you can to a small eeprom, since you can write it in different places.  The critical question then becomes if all the pieces of the sd  card system are well engineered: often at least some are not.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I am not using an SD card, but using internal memory to store the file. I have changed the process, and this time I am not writing to the memory often. I might read/write to the file once a month or something like that. Hope the file has enough life cycle to handle so many writes.

Comment: What "internal memory" ?  The ATmega328 tagged in your question only has eeprom, and program flash, but you can't really put a "file system" in either of those.

Comment: Maybe he means RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the `MCUSR` status register to determine the source of the reset.

Sources can be the Watchdog timer, brownout (too low a voltage), reset (button), or power-cycle.

Comment: Can you explain more? Or point to a tutorial about using MCUSR? Thanks

Comment: try https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/34331/run-different-code-on-different-type-of-reset-in-arduino-nano/34332#34332 .

Comment: Also https://arduino.stackexchange.com/search?q=MCUSR

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question asked, so much as a strategy for different goals.  The comments clarify that the desire is for saving state, so this won't help.